# Difference between in time and before time

Tags: phrase-choice, time

> My boss gave me a task with the completion date 31 March, 2016. I completed the task on 28 February, 2017.

He can label my work in one of six ways:

- Achieved before time
- Achieved in time
- Achieved after target date
- Not achieved
- Will be achieved in time
- Will not be achieved in time.

Which is the appropriate answer from the above six?

Comment: I notice that in your original question, the target date was in 2017, not 2016. Is this a typo? If it is, my answer is completely incorrect, and should be 'in time'.

Comment: @Σωκράτης - I agree. "Achieved after target date" is almost an understatement for work that is turned in almost a year late.

Answer (score 0):

> Achieved after target date

This is because you did achieve it (so it cannot be called 'not achieved' or 'will be achieved'), but only after the target date (so it cannot be called 'before' or 'in time').

As a note, 'achieved before time' is not an expression that is commonly used.